# Changing Position of Image margin after the grid is tapped

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

So, I was trying to make a ripple effect when the grid is tapped in UWP.

For my XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Tapped="MyBorder_Tapped">
        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ripple.gif" Height="40" Width="40"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="Start"  Margin="440,230,0,0"></TextBlock> 
</Grid>
```

As you can see, I have included an image and a text. I included a text for the tapped event purpose only.

For the CS code:

```
private void MyBorder_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Point touchPosition = e.GetPosition(MyGrid);
            MyImage.Margin = new Thickness(touchPosition.X, touchPosition.Y, 0, 0);
            MyTextBlock.Margin = new Thickness(touchPosition.X, touchPosition.Y, 0, 0);

        }
```

As for the TextBlock, it changes the margin correctly, however, for the image object, I don't know the reason why it has an offset.

Here is a sample screenshot of the output:

[image: TextBlock start and gif ripple]

Note: The location of the TextBlock text is the one where i tapped the grid, and as you can see the offset between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the *Image* has default *Horizonal/VerticalAlignment* set to stretch, if you change it to *Left/Top* it should calculate the margin as you want - from top left corner:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Tapped="MyBorder_Tapped">
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="Start"  Margin="440,230,0,0"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

However you may think of making separate control for this, maybe use some *RenderTransform* with offset instead of manipulating margins. Though, this depends on your needs.

Other way to apply the offset:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="-20" Y="-20"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: Woah! Thank you so much!! I did not know that I still need to set the vertical and horizontal alignment in order for me to set the margin of an image!! But can I ask,  one last question? Do you know how can I make the margin of the image point to the center of the image, because I think it points to the top left margin of the object? Am I right? I tried modifying the margin by adding the actual width + x and actual height + y but still did not make it at the center. Is it possible?

Comment: @GarryStephenson In your sample you have hardcoded the Image height/width to 40, so in the very simple case, you can just substract the half of the value to make the image appear centered under mouse position: `MyImage.Margin = new Thickness(touchPosition.X - 20, touchPosition.Y - 20, 0, 0);`. You may also use the RenderTransform like in the edited code.

Comment: You may also want to think about using a Canvas and Canvas.Top/Canvas.Left on your child elements instead of a Grid with Margin.

Comment: @Romasz Thank you so much for your help! Hahaha, i did the exact opposite of what you have told me, and thank you again for the code, will gladly study regarding the render transform! ^_^

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT will do buddy! But for the meantime, I will study manipulating items first in the grid. Thank you for your suggestion! ^_^